# Can I connect one end of an in wall wire to an electrical plug?

Tags: wiring

I ran wire for a ceiling mounted projector to my utility room. I have a server rack in the room with a surge protector. I would like to wire the exposed end with a plug in order to connect the projector to the surge protection provided in the server rack, as I do not have whole house surge protection. Is there a reason this would not be acceptable?

Outlet <--> wire through ceiling <--> out in unfinished room <--> male electrical plug <--> surge protector

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best bet is to install an inlet where you're transitioning from cord to fixed wiring.  You don't want to run flexible cords through walls/ceilings, so you'll want to find a way to avoid that.

[image]

So you'll end up with something as follows:

Surge protector -> male end plug -> cord -> female end -> inlet -> fixed wiring -> receptacle where projector can plug in.